# Problem with MYSQL Connector/C++: crashes before all

Tags: c++, mysql, mingw-w64, connector

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

int testsql() {

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Let's have MySQL count from 10 to 1..." << endl;

    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "37975");

    delete con;
    cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int main(void)
{

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}
```

The above is the codes I copied from the Internet. It compiles but crashes when running. I use MinGW-W64. When I run the program under Eclipse, the program terminated with exit value -1,073,741,515. The mysql connector is Mysql Connector/C++ 1.1.13. I have no idea. Can some one give me some hint?

Thank you,

Comment: *The above is the codes I copied from the Internet* -- This is the problem with just copying code without knowing what is being done, akin to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).  You don't check if `con` is valid before you use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really understand the code. In fact, I have my own code but it is a little complicated, so I copied the above for simple. My real code run well on Ubuntu. Im trying to compile it under windows. At the first time, i got exactly the error. I dont know why it is like that, then I make an example by copying codes like above. Now I simplify more, and the result is the same.

Comment: Does `driver->connect` return an error?  If so, then you need to check for the error before using `con` in any way.  Same thing with all the other functions -- if they return error codes, check the error codes.  Do not just skip over it and assume those functions returned as if nothing is wrong.

Comment: Please note that I even dont call the function testsql. If I remove the function, It says "Hello world!" as expected.

Comment: I do not know the internals of your sql objects, but it could be that those objects define global and/or static variables, and these objects get created *before* `main` is called.  If that is the case, then maybe the construction of these objects are causing the exception.  But why are you not using a debugger to determine where the crash is?

Comment: Beware mysql is GPL. You might want to try mariadb connector/C instead.

Comment: Many thanks to all. I found that I was missing the file mysqlcppconn.dll. If I run the program from cmd with the .dll present in a same directory, it works well. But in Eclipse, it still crashes. So I will looking for a solution to run in Eclipse if possible.